# What could cause a loss of EXIF data when converting from RAW to JPEG?

Tags: metadata

After I convert my image with Irfanview from NEF to JPEG and copying it in another device, I am losing all my EXIF details. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: How do you convert the image? How do you copy it to another device? Can you give example NEF and JPEG files?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you losing the exif details on the conversion or the copy.

Comment: Recommend closing as "unclear what is being asked"

Comment: I am using irfan view application to convert. after conversion the details are not present.

Comment: Are you losing *all* EXIF metadata, or just some "details"? If the latter, which details?

Comment: shutter speed,iso,fno and exposure bias

Answer (score 1):

Most raw conversion software applications have an option in the settings that allow the user to select whether or not to include the EXIF data when exporting an image.

Since you haven't disclosed what application you are using it is difficult to be more specific about how to check to see if that option is currently set to not include EXIF information when converting and saving a file in a different format such as jpeg.

Comment: I am using irfan view application to convert. after conversion the details are not present.